# plugins popcorn.js not working

Tags: javascript, plugins, popcornjs

I recently started a website that makes use of popcorn.js. As you may know popcorn.js makes use of plugins. Now I'm using the youtube player plugin. It makes use of the swfobject.js. But when the popcorn.js calls it there is no get. And this concerns all of the plugins. I tried by downloading the swfobject and put it in the same map. But then popcorn fails at the following piece of code:

```
    swfobject.embedSWF( "//www.youtube.com/e/" + src + "?" + query + "&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=" + container.id + "&version=3",
                      container.id, width, height, "8", null, flashvars, params, attributes );
```

Does anyone know what is causing the problem in the popcorn.js?

With friendly greetings,

Wesley

Answer (score 0):

Popcorn.js needs to run a server to work properly.